# Kafka Connect: How does Kafka Connect read the latest offset?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

As per my understanding KafkaConnect reads the latest offset from the name of the last file written.
How would it keep track of the last offset it read if the files have been moved from the directory?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on **which** connector

Standalone mode for sinks (can) store an offset file. In Distributed mode, howver, the `connect-offsets` topic is read from.

Connect still maintains a consumer group id, though, so if a file is gone, the protocol is still capable of resuming from the last committed offset.